# SSH into a Vagrant machine with Ansible

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible

Normally, you can ssh into a Vagrant-managed VM with `vagrant ssh`. There are two options:

1. You can use an `insecure_private_key` generated by Vagrant to
   authenticate.
2. Use your own private key - provided that
   `config.ssh.forward_agent` is set to `true`, and the VM is
   configured correctly

I use the second option. S when I run `vagrant ssh`, I ssh into the machine with my custom private key.

Now I need to let Ansible SSH into my Vagrant machine and I do not want to use `Vagrantfile` for it.

So I executed:

`ansible-playbook -i hosts/development --private-key=~/.ssh/id_rsa -u vagrant dev.yml`

And I have this error returned:

> fatal: [192.168.50.5] => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey).
>   while connecting to 192.168.50.5:22

The `hosts/inventory` file holds just the IP of my Vagrant VM (192.168.50.5).

I do not know why Ansible cannot ssh into the VM. It's using exactly the same user (`vagrant`) and key (`id_rsa`) as when executing `vagrant ssh`.

However, there is no problem sshing with `vagrant ssh` while the above would not run.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that port is 22 and not 2222?

Comment: researched a few possibilities after my answer. i believe you have not setup your pubkey in the vm vagrant user's authorized_keys. i don't recommend using your personal keys for vagrant unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem probably lies within your `hosts/inventory` file. You need to add the proper connection configuration for Ansible therein, save and re-run.

```
192.168.50.5 ansible_ssh_port=22 ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If you are not using port `22`, adjust the `ansible_ssh_port` in your hosts file accordingly.

It is also a possibility that you have not setup your pubkey in Vagrant, hence this would also not work. To test this, run:

```
vagrant ssh-config | grep IdentityFile
# result should be your private key and not
#   .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```

If you have not put your `pubkey` in the Vagrant vm, you will need to add that before you can try your private key.

Reference: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters

Reference: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/ssh_config.html

Comment: The reason for me not being able to ssh was that I was using a wrong private key file. The correct key to use was revealed by `vagrant ssh-config`. Thank you!

Comment: I was struggling using a custom inventory file. my issue was I had to specify the custom port number when I was specifying the host in the inventory: `[default]
127.0.0.1:2201` otherwise it defaults to 22 and I could not set this in `ansible.cfg` or `Vagrantfile`

Comment: @Hafiz you can also use `ansible_ssh_port=2201` in the inventory file

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should try using the inventory generated by vagrant.
This will save you from having to maintain an Ansible inventory in addition to your Vagrantfile.

For example, you should find an inventory like this used for `vagrant ssh`:

```sh
cat .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory
>>>
# Generated by Vagrant

default ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_port=2222 ansible_user='vagrant' ansible_ssh_private_key_file='/home/someone/coding-in-a-project/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key'
```

You will be able to run `ansible` ad-hoc commands and `ansible-playbook` commands.
(specify this maybe for your needs : `--private-key=~/.ssh/your_private_key`)

```sh
ansible default -i .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory -m ansible.builtin.shell -a 'echo foobar'
```

```sh
ansible-playbook -i .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory playbook.yml
```

source : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_vagrant.html

Answer (score 1):

For those using an inventory.txt, it will look something like this:

```
[vmgroup]
192.168.56.10

[vmgroup:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/Users/amar/centos7/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```

This private key file location was observed from the output of `vagrant ssh-config` command; Executed while being inside the folder formed with `vagrant init centos/7`

Comment: What flags do I pass to ansible to get it to target vmgroup specified this way?

Answer (score 0):

To let Ansible access into a Vagrant machine via SSH we'll need the following ingredients:

- `vagrant ssh-config` outputs OpenSSH valid configuration to connect to the Vagrant VMs (see [vagrant ssh-config - Command-Line Interface](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/cli/ssh_config) )
- `ansible_ssh_common_args` is always appended to the default command line for ssh commands (see [How to build your inventory - Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html))
- In SSH commands, the option `-F` specifies an alternative per-user configuration file (see [ssh - Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html))

Here's what you could do. First, execute `vagrant ssh-config > .vagrant/ssh-config`. Then, create an inventory file dedicated to Vagrant (e.g. `inventories/vagrant.yml`) with the following contents:

```
all:
  hosts:
    vagrant-host-1:
    vagrant-host-2:
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_common_args: -F .vagrant/ssh-config
```

You're ready to let Ansible SSH into Vagrant VMs by adding `-i inventories/vagrant.yml` to the commands! For example, you could run the following command to test the connection:

```
ansible -i inventories/vagrant.yml all -m ping
```