# Ansible can't connect to Vagrant VM (Permission denied)

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible

I've put together a VM using Vagrant (Virtualbox is the provider) for a server I'm setting up. I can SSH into the VM using `vagrant ssh` and `ssh vmname`, but when I run `ansible-playbook -vvvv /path/to/playbook.yml`, I get a "permission denied" error when Ansible tries to connect to the VM.

It's too long to post the results of running the playbook here, so I've [uploaded it to Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/E9kM32C9) instead.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH into a Vagrant machine with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748585/ssh-into-a-vagrant-machine-with-ansible)

Comment: The reason for me not being able to ssh was that I was using a wrong private key file. The correct key to use was revealed by vagrant ssh-config. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your playbook try connecting to the target vm with user `root` but that doesn't exist in the vm.

To double-check it, I think you get an error trying to login to the VM using

```
ssh root@vmname
```

Because you are sure that the `vagrant` user exists in the VM, setting `remote_user` as `vagrant` in `/path/to/playbook.yml` should solve your problem:

```
remote_user: vagrant
```

Otherwise, you can run ansible-playbook with options -u and -k

```
ansible-playbook /path/to/playbook.yml -u vagrant -k
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a ansible.cfg inside your current dir? Ansible could be using these configurations, made for another environment connection (different user, like the first answer here) and be impacting your directly connection. If so, try to hide your ansible.cfg file with:

```
mv ansible.cfg .ansible.cfg
```